# php - Sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I'm still using `mysql_` ext in an old project, so `mysql_real_escape_string()` is enough to prevent sql injection ? Or I have to use `expressions` ?

Comment: I said I'm still using `mysql_` ext !!!

Comment: Has been answered. Search for "Is mysql_real_escape_string enough" and similar. No need to ask the same question over and over again. Also you've tagged your question PDO.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you're trying to reference. You wouldn't typically use `mysql_real_escape_string` if the value was an `int` or `double`. However, if it's a string (and you pay attention when you insert data that could have been manipulated by someone other than you) you should be safe.

PDO isn't the end-all to injection, but it does make things a lot simpler. But, `mysql_*` has been used successfully for years and doesn't make a site any less secure (just depends on who wrote the site).

Comment: so `mysql_real_escape_string` works good for strings ? and I don't have to use `expressions` ?

Comment: It's an either/or kind of things. Either use `mysql_*` or use PDO and expressions. You wouldn't have a hybrid of both.